# React, should a hook result be passed down from parent to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Very often when using a hook on a parent component one of its children will also need to use it. Is it better (performance / readability wise) to pass a function that we get from a hook down to a child component or to get it from scratch?

[Here's a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-danny-2hkosn?file=/src/App.js) of what I mean:

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

// Parent component
export default function App() {
  const { t: formatMessage } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{formatMessage("Welcome to React")}</p>
      <MyButton1 text="Click me!" formatMessage={formatMessage} />
      <MyButton2 text="Click me!" />
    </div>
  );
}

// Option 1: pass formatMessage as a prop
const MyButton1 = ({ text, formatMessage }) => {
  return <button>{formatMessage(text)}</button>;
};

// Option 2: create a new instance of useTranslation
const MyButton2 = ({ text }) => {
  const { t: formatMessage } = useTranslation();

  return <button>{formatMessage(text)}</button>;
};
```

Both components work, but `<MyButton1 />` gets the `formatMessage` function directly from his parent, and `<MyButton2 />` creates a new instance. I've seen code bases that use both options. Which one do you think is the best one?

Comment: There's no generic answer--it depends on how independent you need the component to be. `MyButton2` can be used anywhere as an independent component that handles its own translations, `MyButton1` is reliant on its parent to do the translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First case:

If a `Child` component is a direct child of a `Parent` component that has called the hook, and `Child` will always receive the needed prop everywhere it is used, I think it is better to use the first option, as it will result to fewer function calls. It depends on what the hook does, but it may save some CPU usage.

### Second case:

If `Child` is deep nested, the second option may make sense as otherwise, it will result in what is known as [Prop Drilling](https://dev.to/codeofrelevancy/what-is-prop-drilling-in-react-3kol). Also, if you want `Child` to be completely independent of its parent, you would wanna go with the second option.

Comment: Maybe, but the difference in CPU usage will be almost zero--the biggest issue is coupling and whether or not that coupling matters.

Comment: If you are a serious programmer you care about CPU usage. Also, for readability, you don't want the hook function to print tens or hundreds of times. Where possible you want it to print only once.

Comment: @Tom if you care about CPU usage, you don't use react.